# OpenMP parallel for-loop output

Tags: openmp

I'm new to Openmp and parallel programming.When I parallelize this for loop, output values change.Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

```
for (int m = 0; m < D; m++)
 {

       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) Used[i] = false;

         for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
             {
               if (Used[j] == false)
                {
                int t = powf(2, m);
                U[j + t] = T[j] + U[j + t];
                T[j] = T[j + t] = T[j] + T[j + t]; 
                Used[j] = Used[j + t] = true;
                }

             }
        cout << "\nResult of Step " << m + 1 << " Is :
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << "\n T" << i << ":" << T[i] << "\t U" << i << ":" << U[i];
        cout << "\nTo Continue Press Any Key...";
        _getch();
    }
```

Comment: You ask for help with an OpenMP code but show no OpenMP code.

Comment: The code posted cannot be used to reproduce the problem, so it's impossible for anyone to help you. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score -1):

guess some thread writes in j+t in between.
first:

```
int jt = powf(2, m)+j;
var a = T[j];
U[jt] +=a; 
var b= T[jt];
T[j] = T[jt] = a+b;
```

second, write exact your Openmp code to see the mistake